# Getting UIWebView deprecated warning email from apple when using quickblox (bolts dependency)

Tags: ios, uiwebview, quickblox, bolts-framework

I used quickblox chat sdk. Quickblox sdk has bolts dependency. In bolts framework there is UIWebView used.
So it is chance that apple will reject application.
Updated quickblox + bolt library is required!

Comment: UIWebView was deprecated in iOS 12, but your app won't be rejected if you use it. If you build for a lower target than 12.0, the warning will also disappear.

Comment: @David My current Deployment Target is 11.0. And I am getting warning email that says "Apple will stop accepting submission of apps that use UIWebView APIs."

Comment: @Parimal Did you solve this?